# Почему QPropertyAnimation создает анимацию с нежелательным эффектом движения?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, анимация, qpropertyanimation

Выполните следующую анимацию с помощью `QPropertyAnimation`. Эффект, которой заключается в создании анимации слайда слева.

Проблема в том, что справа, где начинает появляться белое окно, кажется, что окно мигает.

Визуально это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**first.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QPushButton
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from segunda import MainTwo


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.Boton = QPushButton(self)
        self.Boton.setText("Press")
        self.Boton.clicked.connect(self.AnimaOrigen)

        self.next = MainTwo()

    def AnimaOrigen(self):
        #self.AnimaFunction()
        print(self.geometry())

        self.anima = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b'geometry')
        self.anima.setDuration(5000)
        self.anima.setStartValue(QtCore.QRect(self.x(),self.y(),self.width(),self.height()))
        self.anima.setEndValue(QtCore.QRect(self.x(),self.y(),self.width()-self.width(),self.height()))
        self.anima.start()
        self.AnimaFunction()

    def AnimaFunction(self):
        print(self.geometry(),"dos")
        self.next.resize(0,0)
        self.anima1 = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.next, b'geometry')
        self.anima1.setDuration(5000)
        self.anima1.setStartValue(QtCore.QRect(self.x()+830,self.y(),0,self.height()))
        self.anima1.setEndValue(QtCore.QRect(self.x(),self.y(),800,self.height()))
        self.anima1.start()
        self.next.show()


app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
m.resize(800,600)
m.setStyleSheet("Background:red;")
app.exec_()
```

**segunda.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class MainTwo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.Label = QLabel(self)
        self.Label.setText("Soy la segunda ventana")
        self.Label.resize(200,200)
```

---

Я не знаю, приводит ли это к несовместимости драйверов или *Directx*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-моему, метод `def AnimaOrigen(self):` лишний

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtCore
#from segunda import MainTwo


class MainTwo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.Label = QLabel(self)
        self.Label.setText(" Я второе окно !")
        self.Label.resize(200,200)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.close() 
        event.accept()


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.Boton = QPushButton(self)
        self.Boton.setText("Press")
#        self.Boton.clicked.connect(self.AnimaOrigen)           # ---
        self.Boton.clicked.connect(self.AnimaFunction)          # +++

        self.next = MainTwo()

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, timeout=self.close)
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)                         

    """
    def AnimaOrigen(self):
        #self.AnimaFunction()
        print(self.geometry())
        self.anima = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b'geometry')
        self.anima.setDuration(5000)
        self.anima.setStartValue(QtCore.QRect(self.x(),self.y(),self.width(),self.height()))
        self.anima.setEndValue(QtCore.QRect(self.x(),self.y(),self.width()-self.width(),self.height()))
        self.anima.start()
        self.AnimaFunction()
    """ 

    def AnimaFunction(self):
        self.timer.start(5100)              # Если вам надо закрыть первое окно

        print(self.geometry(),"dos")
        self.next.resize(0,0)
        self.anima1 = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.next, b'geometry')
        self.anima1.setDuration(5000)
        self.anima1.setStartValue(QtCore.QRect(self.x()+830,self.y(),0,self.height()))
        self.anima1.setEndValue(QtCore.QRect(self.x(),self.y(),800,self.height()))
        self.anima1.start()
        self.next.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication([])
    m = Main()
    m.show()
    m.resize(800,600)
    m.setStyleSheet("Background: red;")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]